# Having Issues With Fraction To Decimal Converter

Tags: java

I have tested the numbers and they hold the correct values but it is printing out the end result completely wrong. E.X: If I put 2/4, it outputs 1

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FractionConverter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Welcome To The JEM Fraction Converter!\n");

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String num = "0", choice;

        System.out.println("Would You Like To Convert From 'Fraction - Decimal'(a) or 'Decimal - Fraction'(b)?");
        choice = sc.nextLine();

        if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("a")) {

            System.out.println("Please Enter A Fraction (x/y)");
            num = sc.nextLine();

        String[] parts = num.split("/");

        String numerator = parts[0];

        String denominator = parts[1];

        double result = Double.parseDouble(numerator);
        double result2 = Double.parseDouble(numerator);

        System.out.println("\n" + numerator + "/" + denominator + " In Decimal Form Is: " + (result/result2));

        }

    }
}
```

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line:

```
double result2 = Double.parseDouble(numerator);
```

with this:

```
double result2 = Double.parseDouble(denominator);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    double result = Double.parseDouble(numerator);
    double result2 = Double.parseDouble(numerator);
```

... I suppose is a copy/paste problem, isn't it? (both times numerator)